# How to ask someone/a group of people about a match result?

Tags: sentence-usage

Please imagine that someone or a group of people are watching a soccer / basketball / etc match and you are just joining them and you are not aware about the match result/score. What is the normal way to ask about the current result?

Also, please let me know, what would you probably ask at the end of the match when the game has ended and the winner has been defined already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be enough in most cases:

> - What's the score?
> - How did the game end?
> - What's the final score?

Comment: Thank you @virolino. Isn't it possible to ask: **what was the score?** when the match ends?

Comment: Of course you can adapt it to the situation. If the game ended, you will use past tense.